# Is there a way to capture/scrape an entire table instead of cell by cell with the Cheerio library?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

My **scraper** functions runs in O(n^2), takes 6 seconds to execute and I'm looking at ways to optimize.

The source site I'm **scraping** is [www.rate.am/en](http://www.rate.am/en). Screen shot below
[image]

**Scraper** function

```
const rp = require("request-promise");
const $ = require("cheerio");
const url = "http://rate.am/en/armenian-dram-exchange-rates/banks/non-cash";

const TABLE_ROW_IDS = [
  "69460818-02ec-456e-8d09-8eeff6494bce",
  "0fffdcc4-8e36-49f3-9863-93ad02ce6541",
  "65351947-217c-4593-9011-941b88ee7baf",
  "8e9bd4c8-6f4a-4663-ae86-b8fbaf295030",
  "ebd241ce-4a38-45a4-9bcd-c6e607079706",
  "466fe84c-197f-4174-bc97-e1dc7960edc7",
  "5ee70183-87fe-4799-802e-ef7f5e7323db",
  "f3ffb6cf-dbb6-4d43-b49c-f6d71350d7fb",
  "b5bb13d2-8a79-43a8-a538-ffd1e2e21009",
  "db08ff22-add9-45ea-a450-1fe5b1993704",
  "2119a3f1-b233-4254-a450-304a2a5bff19",
  "989ba942-a5cf-4fc2-b62e-3248c4edfbbc",
  "e1a68c2e-bc47-4f58-afd2-3b80a8465b14",
  "332c7078-97ad-4bf7-b8ee-44d85a9c88d1",
  "133240fd-5910-421d-b417-5a9cedd5f5f7"
];

const rateScraper = () => {
  return (
    rp(url)
      .then(url => {
        let resultsArr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < TABLE_ROW_IDS.length; i++) {
          let currencyArr = [];
          let bankName = $(
            `tbody > tr[id=${TABLE_ROW_IDS[i]}] > td:nth-child(2) > a`,
            url
          ).text();

          for (let j = 6; j <= 13; j++) {
            currencyArr.push(
              $(
                `tbody > tr[id=${TABLE_ROW_IDS[i]}] > td:nth-child(${j})`,
                url
              ).text()
            );
          }
          resultsArr.push({
            bankName,
            usd: { buy: currencyArr[0], sell: currencyArr[1] },
            eur: { buy: currencyArr[2], sell: currencyArr[3] },
            rub: { buy: currencyArr[4], sell: currencyArr[5] },
            gbp: { buy: currencyArr[6], sell: currencyArr[7] }
          });
        }
        return resultsArr;
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      })
  );
};
module.exports = rateScraper;
```

The `TABLE_ROW_IDS` are a constant that are unique to each row. The first loop iterates over each row and the second loop extracts the individual rates in each cell.

I suspect that the dozens of Cheerio calls are expensive and I'm looking for a way to extract the entire table all at once to parse.

Edit: Optimized code

```
const rateScraper = () => {
  let start = Date.now();

  return got(url)
    .then((response) => {
      let resultsArr = [];
      const $ = cheerio.load(response.body);
      $("#rb > tbody > tr")
        .filter((i, el) => TABLE_ROW_IDS.includes(el.attribs.id))
        .each((i, elem) => {
          const cells = $(elem).find("td");
          resultsArr.push({
            bankName: cells.eq(1).text(),
            usd: { buy: cells.eq(5).text(), sell: cells.eq(6).text() },
            eur: { buy: cells.eq(7).text(), sell: cells.eq(8).text() },
            rub: { buy: cells.eq(9).text(), sell: cells.eq(10).text() },
            gbp: { buy: cells.eq(11).text(), sell: cells.eq(12).text() },
          });
        });
      let end = Date.now();
      console.log("time", end - start);
      return resultsArr;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
};
module.exports = rateScraper;
```

Comment: I can almost guarantee that the bottleneck is your network and not cheerio.

Comment: @pguardiario I think you're right about the network, I ran it again on a diff network and it's consistently at 2.5 seconds. However, that still feels too long.

Comment: I would try: * switching to axios / https, * sending gzip headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the main thing in my opinion is that you don't want to make it traverse the whole document to find each thing, you want to find the rows, and then traverse just the row to get each cell.  Currently each time you do

```
$(
    `tbody > tr[id=${TABLE_ROW_IDS[i]}] > td:nth-child(${j})`,
    url
).text()
```

you have to traverse the whole thing.

In pure JS on the page, you could do:

```
Array.from(
    document.getElementById('rb').querySelectorAll('tr')
).filter((a) => TABLE_ROW_IDS.includes(a.id))
.map((row) => {
    const cells = row.querySelectorAll('td');
    return { 
        bankName: cells[1].innerText, 
        usd: { buy: cells[5].innerText, sell: cells[6].innerText },
        eur: { buy: cells[7].innerText, sell: cells[8].innerText },
        rub: { buy: cells[9].innerText, sell: cells[10].innerText },
        gbp: { buy: cells[11].innerText, sell: cells[12].innerText }
    };
});
```

So translate to cheerio?  I'm guessing it would be something like:

```
.then(url => {
    const results = [];
    $('#rd > tr', url).filter(() => TABLE_ROW_IDS.includes(this.id)).each((i, elem) => {
        const cells = $(this).find('td');
        results.push({ 
            bankName: cells.eq(1).text(), 
            usd: { buy: cells.eq(5).text(), sell: cells.eq(6).text() },
            eur: { buy: cells.eq(7).text(), sell: cells.eq(8).text() },
            rub: { buy: cells.eq(9).text(), sell: cells.eq(10).text() },
            gbp: { buy: cells.eq(11).text(), sell: cells.eq(12).text() }
        });
    });
```

Comment: This still does rows x cells calls to cheerio methods. The question was how to get it all in 1 call (which I don't think is possible)

Comment: @dave thanks for suggesting traversing each row instead of by cell. I think my biggest obstacle is the jquery syntax used. The `this` in the filter and each methods referenced an empty object. I was able to pull the id in the filter method by accessing `data.attribs.id`. However, I'm not sure what `this` in `const cells = $(this).find('td') ` should be referencing.

Comment: `this` should work if you look [here](https://cheerio.js.org/#each-functionindex-element-), but you could probably just do `$(elem).find` or maybe just `elem.find`, it just needs to be a reference to the current element form the `.each`

Comment: @dave $(elem) seemed to work whereas `this` did not. I was able to get it down from ~2000ms to ~750ms. Thanks for the help!